# Partial series based on geometrical series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Hello I calculated following sum problem but the sample solution for this problem is differs from mine.
However, I think there might be a mistake in the sample solution at least I cannot understand it.

**Task:** Calculate the sum depending on n.

$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{3^{k-2} } {5^{k-1}} $

**Part of the Sample Solution:** 
$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{3^{k-2} } {5^{k-1}} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{3^{k} } {5^{k+1}}$ 

They do this index shift without changning **n** to **n-2** which is why what I dont understand.

**Part of my Solution** 
$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{3^{k-2} } {5^{k-1}} = \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{3^{k}*3^{-2} } {5^{k}*5^{-1}} =
\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{3^{k}*3^{-2} } {5^{k}*5^{-1}} = \frac{5}{9} [(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{3^{k}} {5^{k}}) - (\frac{3^0}{5^0} + \frac{3^1}{5^1})] $

Solve from there using the formula for the **geometrical series* 

Is there something I did wrong or is the Sample solution wrong?
Or Both :)

Comment: $\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{3^{k-2} } {5^{k-1}}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-2} \frac{3^{j}}{5^{j+1}}$ by substitution $j=k-2$. Then change dumb index $j$ to $k$.

Comment: Upper value of summation index must change to $n-2$.

Comment: "... is the Sample solution wrong?" I think so. You can verify that is wrong by plugging some values of $n$ if you still have doubts.

Comment: Yes, the sample solution is wrong. The right hand side has term $\frac {3^n}{5^{n+1}}$ which does not appear on the left side.

Comment: I saw it again but this time with a regular series. $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{3^{k-2} } {5^{k-1}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{3^{k} } {5^{k+1}}$ 
This is valid because $$\infty -2 = \infty $$ correct? I think this is what they meant in their solution

Comment: @ Ivan Kaznacheyeu I dont see what this would be good for. I would still have to add n-1 and n-2 anyway. As the Geo series formula is only valid for $\sum_{k=0}^n $